# div rendering outside container

Tags: css, html, containers

I've started a template on a page and for some reason one of my DIVs (`#content`) is rendering outside the main "container" div. I've looked and looked and can't find anything is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Kiz

CSS:

```
#container {
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#000;
}

#top {
height:100px;
margin:0px 0px 50px 0px;
background-color:#F00;
}

#navigation {
width:720px;
height:100px;
float:left;
background-color:#0F0;
}

#logo {
width:180px;
height:100px;
float:right;
background-color:#00F;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}

#content {
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#FF0;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    <div id="navigation">Navigation goes here</div>
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="clear" />
  </div>
  <div id="content">Content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Looks fine to me.](http://jsbin.com/agupox)

Comment: Where exactly is `#content` rendering? The code looks fine.

Comment: I forgot to add overflow:auto as @benhowdle89 pointed out. It was rendering outside the container...

Comment: This is what I call html-magic: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/qxYHN/
As you can see, when you add a border or a little padding to #container, then the black background of #container comes visible. I have this anomaly before, but I cant remember my fix for it..at lest for now..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#container {
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Awesome that worked, thought it was something silly like that. :S Thanks!

Comment: @benhowdle89 sorry, this answer is 5 years ago, why was the content rendering outside the parent div? and why did overflow: auto fixed this problem? I spent 3 hours trying to fix it and couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Ok the issue seemed to be that your clear: both; elements were unclosed div's. Should have been br tags. So basically, that seemed to solved most of the stuff. Thou not sure, why the #top should be set height: 100px;, if the elements inside set the height anyway..even though they are floating.. then  will set the ending.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/qxYHN/1/

Comment: I basically solved a very critical issue in your layout and my way doesnt need overflow: auto;.. But whatever...

Comment: I don't see what the "critical" issue is, it validates as XHTML 1.0 strict just fine...

Comment: Ok, what first appeared critical, is not. However, still using br instead of div as the clear: both; variable, seems to eliminating the #container not displaying-properly-issue.

Comment: I see. It wasn't that the #container wasn't displaying properly. The '#content' was displaying outside the '#container'. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too and mine problem was a extra closing div so i removed that and it fixed.